# Cannot specify explicit initilizer for arrays with pointers

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

I am compiling with VS2013 and I am having a problem for the below code since I am receiveing an error cannot specify explicit initilizer for arrays:

```
struct OctreeNode
    {
        OctreeNode* child[8] = { nullptr };

        std::vector<const Extents *> nodeExtentsList; 
        Extents nodeExtents;
        bool isLeaf = true;
    };
```

Error I get:

> Error 3   error C2536: 'BVH::Octree::OctreeNode::BVH::Octree::OctreeNode::child' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays

If anyone faced this problem please advise.

Comment: vs2013 is VERY old and VERY non-compliant.   Please try to update to the newest version if at all possible.  Regardless, please post the actual error message you are getting.

Comment: Your code is fine and compiles here. Upgrade to VS2017.

Comment: Error 3 error C2536: 'BVH::Octree::OctreeNode::BVH::Octree::OctreeNode::child' : cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays 
this is the error message. I dont want to switch to newer VS because  have other issues :)

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to upgrade to VS2017 you have to cope with that and initialize your array differently, for example in a constructor (struct's can have constructors in C++):

```
struct OctreeNode
{
  OctreeNode* child[8];

  std::vector<const int *> nodeExtentsList;
  int nodeExtents;
  bool isLeaf = true;

  OctreeNode() { for (auto & p : child) p = nullptr; }; //<< constructor
};
```

and if that doesn't compile, try this constructor:

```
OctreeNode()
  { for (int i = 0; i < _countof(child); i++) child[i] = nullptr; };
```